# I think I just found the encryption key used by ransomware on my server... how can I check?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, malware

Long story short, server ended up with a ton of encrypted files.

IDRansomware thinks it was GlobeImposter 2.0, see [here](https://id-ransomware.malwarehunterteam.com/identify.php?case=7251744e465168990612f3b748b46301eca08c14).
I'm not 100% sure on that as I ended up with a ..rtf file extension on my files (intentional double-dots there) and that isnt stated on the info sheet for globe imposter 2.0.

Anyway, I have been tidying up the FS and I've come across this file...

[image]

The timestamp on the file puts it at the time of the attack and it occurs to me that the ransomware never finished its job - we spotted it and killed it.
I wonder if I get extremely lucky and it hadnt removed the key it was using and thats what I've found.

Which leads me to my question... how would I go about testing this against one of my encrypted files?

I would normally just restore from backup but it encrypted my backup metadata files, so they're gone. :(
Luckily I have encrypted versions and non encrypted versions of some files I'm hoping I can use to test, I just have no idea how to go about that.

Any help appriciated!!!

Comment: The second bit looks like hex, but I've pasted it in a hex to text converter and it didn't give me much useful :(

Comment: Let's assume you found the key. according to: https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/analysis-of-new-globeimposter-ransomware-variant.html it's using RSA. RSA is asymmetric encryption: having the encryption key won't help you for the reverse operation

Comment: Almost just looks like a fingerprint. Not seeing an identifier block e.g private or public

Comment: You have a couple of options that I can see: `1.` Restore what you can from backup and rebuild the rest. `2.` Contact a data recovery company that specializes in ransomware recovery. `3.` Pay the ransom.